# Change font for the title of Navigation Header bar in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, react-native

In the new version i.e, the 0.61 of react-native, I didn't find any sort of mechanism for changing the font of the title. The earlier versions have their own solutions but the present one doesn't have one, which in turn prompted me to ask the question. How do you change the font?

Comment: which navigation library do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use for navigation in "reactnavigation" library

Do it that way

[As described in the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html)

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  };

  /* render function, etc */
}
```